# Is there a way for automatic ODM for MongoDB in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is there any way to have out-of-the-box, automatic ODM for Python and MongoDB? For Java the MongoDB driver does everything: I can just dump object of my custom class and load it later, the driver does automatic type checking, mapping etc., I don't have to change anything in my code. Is this possible for Python and PyMongo, MongoEngine etc.? Something like:

```
class MyClass:
    # definition

obj = MyClass()
db.save(obj)  # automatically creates JSON
obj = db.findOne({"name": "John Smith"})
```

Comment: As long as you define the fields of your Document class, Mongoengine can do that for you, see example from doc https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine#examples

Comment: @bagerard I do know about MongoEngine. I want something else, something like Java driver: no StringFields, nothing explicit, just silent serialization and deserialization. I just want regular strings, integers, nested objects etc. in my classes, save it to MongoDB and load it from it. I understand it's not possible then?

Comment: Try inheriting from DynamicDocument instead of DOcument, although I wouldn't recommend it, it may work for your use case. See doc here http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html

Answer (score -1):

[pymodm](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm) is the Python ODM for MongoDB.

Comment: Developement stopped since October 2020